# Framework for building REST API in Node.js

Tags: javascript, web-development, node.js

There are lots of frameworks available for Node.js like `Express`, `Hapi`, `Restify`, etc to name a few. Being a new developer to the node ecosystem these choices are confusing me. And I couldn't find any resource that puts these frameworks face to face.

Could you please discuss your choice of framework and how it enhanced your encounter with Node.js. Please consider pointing out the **pros** and **cons** of your choice.

Just like me, I believe there are lots of others who would benefit from these recommendations.

My current use scenario - building a data read/write heavy REST API.

Comment: Please describe which feature *you* value the most.

Comment: THis site isn't really for discussion but rather for answers - ie change this to say what framework would you recommend given x y z requirements.

Comment: @ everyone else who's put this on hold: if you're voting it really is best to give a comment so that the user can improve their question.

Comment: I'm not sure that clarification really helps on whether this is on-topic or off-topic. Also, I recommend rephrasing "Could you please discuss..."